# Not able to add storybook to Nrwl Nx angular application

Tags: angular, storybook, nrwl, nrwl-nx, angular-storybook

Getting the below error when i try to add storybook to an existing Nrwl Nx monorepo angular application.

The command i used is `nx g @nrwl/angular:storybook-configuration <project name>`

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@nrwl/workspace/src/command-line/supported-nx-commands'
Require stack:
- /Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-local.js
- /Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-global.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
Shawns-MBP:ktp-web shawntony$ nx g @nrwl/angular:storybook-configuration modules-qbuilder
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@nrwl/workspace/src/command-line/supported-nx-commands'
Require stack:
- /Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-local.js
- /Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-global.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.initLocal (/Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-local.js:12:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js:12:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-local.js',
    '/Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-global.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you install @nrwl/storybook as a dev dependency?

Comment: It's helpful if you post the results of "nx report" so we know what version you're working with